# Operation of "mv" described in "Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment"

Tags: files, filesystems, mv

In [Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment (book)](http://www.apuebook.com/) Section 4.14, interpret the i-node and directory, there is a paragraph:

> When renaming a file without changing file systems, the actual contents of the file need not be moved--all that needs to be done is to add a new directory entry that points to the existing i-node and then unlink the old directory entry. For example, to rename the file `/usr/lib/foo` to `/usr/foo`, the contents of the foo needn't be moved if the directories `/usr/lib` and `/usr` are on the same filesystem. This is how the `mv` command usually operates.

According to that, a filename of a file should include the path to that file, and "mv" doesn't really move the file. But why the time it takes to move the two files under the same directory differs according to their size?

Comment: *"But why the time it takes to move the two files under the same directory differs according to their size?"* **You need to provide some empirical evidence of this,** because it certainly doesn't seem true to me.  It happens instantly regardless of file size.  You can also confirm that `mv` actually uses `rename()` when that's all it has to do by watching it in `strace`.

Comment: This is my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The path name is inferred from the route from the file's directory entry back to the root, `/`.
2. A file's name is stored in its directory, so the same "file" can be called two different things simultaneously.
3. The time taken to move a file within the same filesystem is independent of the file size.

In response to your statements:

> a filename of a file should include the path to that file

The paragraph does not say that, nor anything resembling that. Perhaps it's in a part that you didn't quote?

> `mv` doesn't really move the file

Yes it does: the file is put into a new directory - possibly with a new name - and removed from the old. This a move, but not a copy (the file's contents are not moved, only its location in the filesystem).

> For example, to rename the file /usr/lib/foo to /usr/foo, the contents of the foo needn't be moved if the directories /usr/lib and /usr are on the same filesystem.

The path `/usr/lib/foo` is decomposed to the filename `foo` within the directory `/usr/lib`. Similarly `/usr/foo` is decomposed to `foo` under `/usr`. If `/usr` and `/usr/lib` are on the same filesystem then the rename becomes a `link`-and-`unlink` operation (the position of the file within the filesystem is moved; the file's contents remain unmoved).

Comment: 1: "a filename of a file should include the path to that file" is my infer according to "rename the file /usr/lib/foo to /usr/foo", why it says "rename"? ............2: my meaning about "mv doesn't really move the file" is that "mv" doesn't move the place of the files' data. Does "mv" move the file's data from one place to another?

Comment: @tiantong I've tried to add clarifications for you in my Answer